# Grunt transforming Font-Awesome into unreadable characters

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, font-awesome

I just upgraded to Sass 3.4.22, and thought that would fix the problem, but no such luck.

I'm using Font-Awesome through my Grunt Project, and when I compile the css, either for our developer servers, or our production servers, Grunt is transforming line such as:

```
.fa-th-large:before {
  content: "\f009";
}
```

to:

```
.fa-th-large:before {
  content: "";
}
```

because of this, it is causing my website to display some very interesting characters instead of the icons that need to be displayed.

Here is a link to our gruntfile.js on [JFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/murphy1976/gbwtyvj3/)

Comment: I'd try it without `unixNewlines: true` to see if that helps

Comment: no such luck. it initially looked like it worked, but 15 minutes later - the wacky characters are back.

Comment: Stupid question of course, but what is the problem? Your "wacky character" is actually U+F009.

Comment: the term wacky and the example given were just examples. The entire font-awesome css, when compiled, is being "re-written", like the compiler itself is translating the UTF-8 code into its respective glyph without the font being attached, so the result is a random display of characters on the website.

Comment: When you say it looked like it worked, what actually happened? Did you remove the line from both the production and development bits?

Comment: Have you checked the the file encoding of the SASS files and output files, I don't know that that would make a difference, but might be worth checking.

Comment: One more thing to check, could it be scsslint be causing the issue? Try disabling that too.

Comment: Just to confirm, you've already tried running just the `sass` task to make sure that it's the culprit?

Answer (score 0):

I went through this issue for couple of days, the only fix was to update Sass

most probably you have an old sass, compare your version by

```
sass --version
```

Just install latest by

```
sudo gem install sass
```

First I thought its grunt issue; however after updating sass all got fixed.